# Normal distribution of urinary bladder

Tags: statistics

Assume that the size of the urinary bladder for men is normally distributed with a mean of 550 ml and a standard deviation of 100 ml.

How big proportion of men in the population have a urinary bladder bigger than 650 ml?

Comment: How big? I'm guessing those men might be slightly bigger than average. Seriously though you should give some idea of your attempts on, and understanding of, this homework-style question.

Answer (score 1):

[image: pic]

In normal distribution about $68.2\%$ of population lies within interval $(m-\sigma, m+\sigma)$. The other part lies outside this interval placed 50-50 on both sides of the interval.

Therefore there is about $\frac{1-.682}{2}\cdot 100\% = 15.9\%$ of population satisfying your condition.